# Iframes and Same-Origin-Policy and reverse proxy hack

Tags: html, security, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have been reading up on Iframes with different domains then the parent document and I am slightly confused.

I understand that if the Iframe is from the same domain as its parent document, the parent document can access the iframe's document. It seems like I could circumvent this with the following hack:

1. I set up a web server at `mydomain.com`
2. I serve the original page from `mydomain.com/index.html`
3. I setup a proxy on my webserver for `mydomain.com/othersite -> site2.com`
4. Add `<iframe src="mydomain.com/othersite">`  to the `mydomain.com/index` page

This seems like it would circumvent the same origin policy and the user would be none the wiser. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is something you are missing.

The Same Origin Policy secures the client-side of website access.

If you setup `mydomain.com/othersite` to be proxied to `site2.com` then the browser would not be sending the user's cookies for `site2.com` to your site at `mydomain.com`. All you would get is the cookies your site had set on `mydomain.com` for that user. That is, all you would be attacking was your `mydomain.com` session with `site2.com`, not the user's session with `site2.com` (as your reverse proxy effectively makes `mydomain.com` the client of this connection).

If there *was a way* to circumvent the Same Origin Policy this would have to be something client-side in order to have the browser send cookies to your domain.

I realise I've concentrated on cookies here, however cookies are an easy to grasp concept of an example of client objects that the Same Origin Policy protects. Your appoach *would* allow you to manipulate the DOM of `site2.com` but it would not be in the context of your visitor's access to `site2.com`, it would be in the context of your own access to `site2.com` - nothing that the visitor accesses could be changed unless they trusted your site enough to log into the proxied version `site2.com` directly.