# How to hide the source URL in an iFrame on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe

I have been reading up on here about how to hide the source URL in an iFrame using Javascript and Jquery, but for some reason, I haven't found a solution that works so far with Wordpress.

So short and sweet, I am trying to hide a URL for competition reasons, I'm about to launch a new web page using an iFrame to display content from another website that I subscribe to and pay quite a bit of money for their services. So I don't want my competition to know about them and copy what I do.

What would be the best way that I could mask the HTML source link in the iFrame? I use the latest version of Wordpress to host my site.

Alternatively, I am open to more advanced solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you realize you cannot hide anything that you're serving to browser, from the user

Comment: This cannot be done with plain HTML or Javascript. There are ways to do this but I hesitate to give those answers because I don't know that you "pay quite a bit of money for their services" and I don't help people steal.

Comment: I'm not stealing anything. I'm a businessman who pays taxes and I pay $1400 per year for the web service that I use and I don't want my competitors STEALING MY set up.

Comment: Can someone please help answer my question? To elaborate, I have spent about 1 month designing something using a third party service which I subscribe to. They then pass me a link to my design as part of the subscription service. So I don't want my competitors to easily find my link and follow part of that link to the third party website and then copying what I have done. It would be easier if the third party service were to install all the code on my domain, but they currently don't offer that service. So instead you subscribe to them and they give you a link.

Comment: P.S The third party service has given me a raw HTML file with my unique URL link @gforce301

Comment: You can't hide the source of a `<iframe>` tag. If it's sent to the browser, then anyone can view the source to get the original URL.

Comment: How about using a reverse proxy? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220712/iframes-and-same-origin-policy-and-reverse-proxy-hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220712/iframes-and-same-origin-policy-and-reverse-proxy-hack)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not stealing anything. I'm a businessman who pays taxes and I pay $1400 per year for the web service that I use and I don't want my competitors STEALING MY set up

Ok I'll take you at face value. As has been pointed out in comments, it's impossible to do this with plain HTML or Javascript. It simply can not be done. There is no way to prevent a user of a browser from seeing the URI's that are contacted. Period.

That being said you could:

- Retrieve the HTML from the 3rd party with your web server using something like CURL in PHP.
- Take the result of the above and send it out on a URL of your choosing.
- Create HTML with an `<iframe>` or whatever else you want to display the content from the 3rd party and point it at your new URL on your web server.

The above is not trivial to do correctly and will require some knowledge and work on your part. One issue with the above method will be: passing along javascript, images, css, etc... correctly so that they appear to come from your server.